# Multi Step Form with buttons, but without next buttons - pass values to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to build a multi step form which only contains of buttons.
Therefore I use `<fieldset>` for every step. On each step, a question is asked and out of a couple of possible answers, only one is correct.

The user makes his decision by clicking on an answer button and automatically the next `<fieldset>` should be shown.

Due to design reasons, there should not be any additional "Next" or "Previous" buttons.

On the last `<fieldset>`, by chosing an answer, the form values should be submitted.

How can I buffer all clicked button values and pass them to PHP to save them to a database later?

I used `<button type="button" value="1" name="capital">Rome</button>` for the buttons except for the ones on the last step, which are of type `submit`.

The file `action.php` only contains a `var_dump($_POST);`, but that remains empty.

Thank you in advance.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;
  var buttonname = '';
  var buttonvalue = '';
  var btnarray = [];
  steps = $(".fieldset").length;
  $(".next").click(function(){
    // $.post("action.php", $("button").serialize());
    buttonname = $(this).attr('name');
    buttonvalue = $(this).val();
    btnarray.push(buttonname+":"+buttonvalue);
    current_step = $(this).parents("fieldset");
    next_step = $("fieldset").eq(current);
    buttonvalue = $(this).val();
    current_step.hide();
    next_step.show();
    setProgressBar(++current);

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "action.php",
       data: { buttonname:buttonname, buttonvalue:buttonvalue },
       success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);

       },
       datatype: "JSON"

    });


  });

  $(".submit").click(function(){
    buttonvalue = $(this).val();
    btnarray.push(buttonvalue);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "action.php",
        data: { formValues : btnarray }
      });
  });


  $(".previous").click(function(){
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(--current);
  });
  setProgressBar(current);
  // Change progress bar action
  function setProgressBar(curStep){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
      .css("width",percent+"%")
      .html(percent+"%");
  }
});
```

```css
.parallelogram {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #0793EB;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #0793EB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg_form" novalidate action="action.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
  <p>What is the capital of Italy?</p>
  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="capital" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Paris</span></button>

  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="capital" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Rome</span></button>
 </fieldset>
 
 <fieldset hidden>
   <p>Which continent is larger?</p>
  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="continent" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Europe</span></button>

  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="continent" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Asia</span></button>
 </fieldset>
 
   <fieldset hidden>
   <p>When did the first world war end?</p>
  <button type="submit" class="parallelogram next" name="warend" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">1918</span></button>

  <button type="submit" class="parallelogram next" name="warend" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">1923</span></button>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Try using a set of `<input type="hidden" name="..." />`, and use them to hold the selected values along the way.

Comment: _“Due to design reasons, there should not be any additional "Next" or "Previous" buttons”_ – so if the user clicks a wrong button, they will not be given a chance to correct that …? Sounds like the “designer” knows nothing about usability. // You would not need to “buffer” any button clicks, if you simply used checkboxes or radio buttons to let the user make their choice - then all you have to do in the end is _send_ the form. (And if the “designer” has objections to checkboxes/radio buttons again - solutions to make those _look different_ exist en masse.)